# Sorting on documents within an array

Tags: mongodb

I've tried very hard to read the documentation on finding and sorting but haven't had luck. I can change my document structure if it's not suitable for the operation I want to do but I'd prefer my current structure.

All users have names and an array of skills, each which have names and associated skill levels. All users have skill levels in every skill.

Here's my structure:

```
{
    "name": "Alice",
    "skills": [
        {
            "name": "gardening",
            "level": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "shopping",
            "level": 7
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Bruce",
    "skills": [
        {
            "name": "gardening",
            "level": 5
        },
        {
            "name": "shopping",
            "level": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have many of these objects, each of them I'll call `Users`. I'd like to sort Users by their Gardening skill `level`.

I know I can access level 10 `Users`, regardless of which skill they're level 10 in, with a find query:

```
{ 'skills.level' : 10 }
```

But I want to sort users by their Gardening skill level, with a sort command like:

```
{ "skills.gardening.level" : 1 }
```

But this doesn't work because of my current structure.

Do I need to change my structure in order to sort like this or can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work without changing your document structure, but the penalty is that the operation will not use an index and will be pretty slow for lots of users. Use the aggregation framework:

```
> db.users.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$skills" },
    { "$match" : { "skills.name" : "gardening" } }
    { "$sort" : { "skills.level" : 1 } }
])
{ "_id" : ObjectId(...), "name" : "Bruce", "skills" : { "name" : "gardening", "level" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(...), "name" : "Alice", "skills" : { "name" : "gardening", "level" : 10 } }
```

In the absence of any other information about how you're using the collection, the simplest change to allow you to sort on individual skill levels is to redesign the documents so that one document represents one skill for one user:

```
{
    "name" : "Alice",
    "skill" : "gardening",
    "level" : 10
}
```

Sorting on `level` for a particular `skill`:

```
db.skills.find({ "skill" : "gardening" }).sort({ "level" : 1 })
```

Index on `{ "skill" : 1, "level" : 1 }`.

Retrieving a collection of documents with equivalent information to your old user document:

```
db.skills.find({ "name" : "Alice" })
```

Index on `{ "name" : 1 }`.

Comment: Great, thanks! I hadn't caught the aggregate framework. Those are two good solutions.